# Convert rows using PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following data :
[image]

I want to present it in the following way using PIVOT:
[image]

I have the following code but I am not getting the desired results.
[image]

Code as follows:

```
Select part_no, part_description, 1 x1 , 2 as x2, 3 as x3
From (
Select part_no, part_description, quantity --, cost
, rn

From (
select part_no, ifsapp.Inventory_Part_API.Get_Description(CONTRACT,PART_NO) as Part_description
, TRUNC(date_applied, 'DAY')+1 start_of_week, Sum( quantity ) quantity
, Sum( ifsapp.Inventory_Transaction_Cost_API.Get_Sum_Unit_Cost(transaction_id, 'TRUE', 'TRUE') *QUANTITY ) as Cost
, rn

from ifsapp.INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST Left Outer Join Rowsnum On TRUNC(date_applied, 'DAY')+1 = dt

where part_no='CUTC12444' and 
direction='-' 
and date_applied between 
    Case When '&No_Of_Weeks' Is Null Then trunc(add_months(sysdate, -11),'mm')
         When '&No_Of_Weeks' Is not Null Then To_Date('&Period_ending_date','DD/MM/YYYY') - ('&No_Of_Weeks'*7) End
   and
    Nvl(To_Date('&Period_ending_date','DD/MM/YYYY'), last_day(trunc(sysdate)) )
 
and contract Not In ('CPH','CTM','VMS','CGP')
Group by part_no, ifsapp.Inventory_Part_API.Get_Description(CONTRACT,PART_NO), TRUNC(date_applied, 'DAY')+1, rn

) data Where Nvl(rn,0) != 0
) src
Pivot
( Sum( Quantity ) for rn In ( 1,2,3 ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into the bulk of your query, the reason you are getting the result you have is that you are doing:

```
Select part_no, part_description, 1 x1 , 2 as x2, 3 as x3
```

Here `1`, `2` and `3` and numeric literals, not values from your subquery.

Your pivot has

```
for rn In ( 1,2,3 )
```

and as you haven't provided aliases the result set will give those columns the same names as the values - but as quoted identifiers (as `1` isn't a valid column name, but `"1"` is - see the [object naming rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) for more).

That means you also need to use quoted identifiers when referring to them:

```
Select part_no, part_description, "1" x1 , "2" as x2, "3" as x3
```

or just

```
Select part_no, part_description, "1" , "2", "3"
```

You could also alias in the pivot clause, either with a prefix as as a full name for each value, or both - some of which would not have to be treated as quoted identifiers.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZvbB2RvS)

---

> what is the easiest way to get a sum of the data in the quantity column as the last column after the pivot

If you want to get it after the pivot then you could just do

```
Select part_no, part_description, "1" , "2", "3", "1" + "2" + "3" as gt
From (
```

But you could make it part of the first subquery instead, with an analytic sum:

```
Select part_no, part_description, "1" , "2", "3", gt
From (
Select part_no, part_description, quantity --, cost
, rn
, sum(quantity) over (partition by part_no, part_description) as gt

From (
```

Comment: Thanks for help, that works perfectly. Just 1 more question, what is the easiest way to get a sum of the data in the quantity column as the last column after the pivot. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YozfR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YozfR.png)

Comment: @Jannette - it's hard to tell what would work best for your query but I've added a couple of options. If those don't help then ask a new question, and include a [mre] with sample data and expected result (not as images), and what you're stuck on.